# Setting permissions so folder can't be deleted (but contents can be modified and deleted)

Tags: file-permissions, windows-server

As a workaround for a bug I need to change the permissions on a folder so it cannot be deleted (by the current user) but the user can create, modify, and delete files and folders in that folder normally. How can I set up permissions to do this -- or is it not possible?

I have Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the folder, grant the user:

- Modify permissions, specifying that they Apply To: *Subfolder and files only*
- The following permissions, specifying that they Apply To: *This folder only*:

  - Traverse Folder / Execute File
  - List Folder / Read Data
  - Read Attributes
  - Read Extended Attributes
  - Create Files / Write Data
  - Create Folders / Append Data
  - Read Permissions

These permissions grant the user the traditional Modify permissions to the folder, with the two exceptions that they CANNOT 1) Rename, or 2) Delete the folder.

Comment: Thank you! I was having a terrible time with an application that mis-manages the folders it sets up in the temp folder and this should keep things running smoothly.